# Duplicate socket.io listener when using useEffect

Tags: sockets, socket.io, react-hooks

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    socket
      .on(conversationName, (message) => {
        // push into list messages a new one 
      });
  }, [conversationName]);
```

When user chose a conversation on the sidebar, a conversation name will be sent back from backend and stored in React state called `conversationName`. I used an useEffect to catch that change

Also a socket is listening on event name `conversationName` to get new messages.

My problem is the message that user sent will be duplicated **n times** when he switch back to a specific conversation **n times**

For example, there are 2 conversations called A and B. He clicks to A, chit chat some messages, clicks to B and then clicks back to A. Any message he sent from now on is duplicated 2 times.

Looking for some advice, many thanks guys !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to [clean up the listener](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect) when the effect fires again:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
    const listener = (message) => {
      // push into list messages a new one 
    };
    socket.on(conversationName, listener);

    return () => socket.off(conversationName, listener);
  }, [conversationName]);
```