# Why React js receive multiple answer from server with Socket.io?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

When emit a event to the websocket server, the server receive the event once and send a response, but the client receive the event multiple time:
[result expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhjDn.png)
[result received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcHEl.png)
client side:

```
client.emit("test", {
  room: props.room,
});
client.on("testResponse", () => {
  console.log("test response app");
});
```

server side :

```
 socket.on("test", (data: { room: string }) => {
console.log("test");
io.in(data.room).emit("testResponse", {});
});
```

Comment: Can you post whole client code? I think you don't wrap the connection to server into useEffect hook, so the connection is created every time the component is rerendered - what can be multiple times.

Comment: Do you have your listeners in a useEffect hook? You may need to clean the client side listener like in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67321559/duplicate-socket-io-listener-when-using-useeffect

Comment: I've got a socket.js where i export my connection to the socket

import io, { Socket } from "socket.io-client";
export const client = socket(url);

and I've got my App.tsx

import { SocketContext, client } from "./service/socket.js";
function App() {
useEffect(() => {
client.on("testResponse", (data: any) => {
console.log("test response app");
        })
    }
}

Maybe I have to had a socket.off ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:
on the client side I got to put the socket.on('response,()=>{...}) in the UseEffect of the component and add a socket.off in the return of the useEffect

```js
 useEffect(() => {
socket.on("testResponse", () => {
  console.log("test response app");
});


 return () => {
      socket.off("testResponse");
    };

});
```